# Laravel accessor returning values of nested relationships which are not required

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Currently I'm stuck in making an accessor. I'm trying to access some values from the nested relationship after when I got that I'm returning the value and appending it to the model, but the problem is inside my response I'm getting values of the relationship which I try to access in my accessor.

```
 public function getTranslatorEmailAttribute()
    {
        if (in_array(AddOnConfirmation::EMAIL, $this->customer->department->company->add_on_confirmation)) {
            return $this->assignedTranslator()->first()->email;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is the customer relation which I'm trying to use

```
 public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->with('customerData.customerType', 'customerData.department.company');
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Here is a screenshot of response I'm getting with using accessor

[image: Postman response]

Comment: you are loading the relationship, when you serialize the model that includes the loaded relationships

Comment: How I can fix this in your opinion? @lagbox

Comment: use something like API Resource or a transformer so you can define the structure of the data being returned

Comment: It can't be possible directly appending the value?

Answer (score 1):

Your GET route that handles api/bookings/{id} should return the resource in the end, something like:

```
return BookingResource::make($booking);
```

Then create BookingResource and likely put it in `namespace App\Http\Resources\Api;`
The file itself can look like:

```
namespace App\Http\Resources\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

/** @mixin \App\Models\Booking */
class BookingResource extends Resource
{

     /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $append = $request->get('append');
        return [
            // Here you'd put everything you want to show
            'id' => $this->id,
            'translator_email' => $append == 'translator_email' ?  $this->translator_email : null,
            // ...
        ];
    }
}
```